# Variable inside a string inside array?

Tags: php

In PHP, I want to create an array of strings with variables, like this:

```
$myarr = array("This is a $animal.", "Something else");
```

What happens if I do this:

```
$animal = "dog";
$myarr = array("This is a $animal.", "Something else");
$animal = "cat";
echo $myarr[0];
```

Will this output "This is a dog." or "This is a cat."

In other words, does a variable inside a string inside an array change?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Answer (score 0):

After a string is defined, it no longer changes. Variable expansion only happens at define-time.

I agree with @esqew though that it would have only taken a second to verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace.

Try this:

```
$myarr = array("This is a animal", "Something else");
$out = str_replace('animal', 'cat', $myarr);
```